# Why is "dyadic" the only word with the prefix "dy-" for "two"?

Tags: etymology, prefixes

I learned that the word "dyadic", a word opposed to monadic, is written with a *y*.

My etymology sources indicates it comes from ["Dyad"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dyad), which means "pair", "couple", "double". However, every other word I know with a "di-" prefix meaning "two" is written with an *i*. (*Dioxyde*, *dipterous*, *dioptre*, *digram*, ... The "*bi-*" prefix is now much more prevalent but every other case of "*di-*" I know uses an *i*)

Even in ancient Greek, there's a difference between the "*δι-*" prefix and the word "*δυάς*", they don't use the same letter, although they both come from the Greek word for "two".

- Why is there a difference in spelling between the Greek word for two and the "di-" prefix?
- Why does "dyadic" seem to be the only word that kept the *y*?

<sub>Note that this seems to date from ancient Greek, so as far as I know it also happens in every language that got these words from Greek, not just English.</sub>

<sub>Note2: I should have specified it, but of course I'm talking about words where the "*dy-*" prefix means "two", so this is not about words like "dynamic" or "dyssentry".</sub>

Comment: There is also dyarchy and dyotheism, but you are right that there don't seem to be many such words.

Comment: "as far as I know it also happens in every language that got these words from Greek" this is not true at least for Italian, Spanish and Serbian

Comment: @fqq My bad, I saw it appearing in French and English. That's why I said "as far as I know"! I assume it was corrected in order to make spelling consistent (for Spanish at least).

Answer (score 14):

The prefix δυ- is from δύω “two” < IE *duō. The prefix δι- is from δίς “twice” < IE *dwi- (the /w/ is lost in Greek). Both are common in Greek.

By the way: “division” is from Latin, not Greek.

There are lots of English words beginning with dyo- and dy-. I suggest you flick through any English dictionary.

Comment: I did look up in a dictionary, but most words are either alternate spelling of more commons "*di-*" words (like *diarchy* or *dioptre*), or words with unrelated etymology, mostly using the "*dys-*" prefix. I edited my question, I should have been clearer. Also, "dyadic" seems to be the only one that *can't* be spelled with "*di-*".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat "Lots" might be an overstatement, but it shows up mostly in technical terms formed from Greek roots. The Christian belief that Christ had two wills, for example, is "dyothelism", a signal that differentiates two different states is "dyotic", a chemical reaction that switches two single bonds at the same time is "dyotropic", a hypothetical particle with both an electric and magnetic charge is a "dyon". It's worth noting that these are mostly modern formations, not ancient ones.

Answer (score 2):

Dyad is a commonly-used musicological term for a two note chords. Pedal steel guitars use this harmonic structure primarily.

Comment: While true, _dyad_ is just the noun form of _dyadic_.

Comment: Like only_pro said, while this is absolutely true, the question excludes this word specifically: "My etymology sources indicates it comes from "Dyad", which means "pair", "couple", "double". However, every **other** word I know…" (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: ah yes, pedal steel guitar morphology for harmonic declension